# I need help understanding a Javascript function used to search a list with a search bar so I can modify it to search a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm working on a college assignment where I use a PHP class to generate table values which a Javascript function then searches with a search bar. It builds off of a previous assignment that uses the same search bar to search an unordered list. It worked great for the list but it uses a function that was already supplied to me which, frankly, I don't know how it works. Now all it does, once I add a table row with more than one cell, is search the first cell. It still returns the whole row but I also need it to search the whole row.

It seems like `a = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];` only returns the first `<a>` and this might be the problem, but I don't know how to go about fixing that in a was that doesn't break the function.

The function that's confusing me follows. I added my own code to it to hide the list/table which obviously I understand. I won't include that but that's why you don't see me close the function, just so you're not confused about that.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); 
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        a = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

For reference, here is the multi-cell table row I added for testing, which is now giving me problems. I also include the actual search bar itself because it contains relevant syntax for explaining the functionality. There are other rows so the table closes later on.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">     <!--This is my search bar-->
<table id="myTable" onload="hideList()">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <?php 
                $pr0 = new productRow(0);
                echo 
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->itemNumber . "</td></a>" . 
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->name . "</td></a>" . 
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->type . "</td></a>" .               //These rows concatenate the class instances with the elements in which they are supposed to appear
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->model . "</td></a>" . 
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->brand . "</td></a>" . 
                    "<td><a href=\"#\">" . $pr0->description . "</td></a>";
            ?>
        </tr>
```

And I'll include the PHP class just so you can see how it inputs things, but don't worry, it works.

```
<?php
    class productRow {
        var $itemNumber = [];
        var $name = [];
        var $type = [];
        var $model = [];
        var $brand = [];
        var $description = [];
        function __construct($i) {                                  //receives argument when class is called with an argument
            $this->itemNumber = $this->make_table_row($i)[0];
            $this->name = $this->make_table_row($i)[1];
            $this->type = $this->make_table_row($i)[2];
            $this->model = $this->make_table_row($i)[3];            //This function allows the instance values of the attributes to be taken from the make_table_row function
            $this->brand = $this->make_table_row($i)[4];
            $this->description = $this->make_table_row($i)[5];
        }
        function make_table_row($i) {                               //receives argument when class is called with an argument
            $row = 1;
            $tablerows = [];
            if (($input = fopen("input.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {                 //gets the CSV with my table data
                while (($tabledata = fgetcsv($input, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {   //cycles through the rows of data creating arrays
                    if ($row == 1) {
                        $row++;     
                        continue;       //skips the first row because it's a header row I don't want on my input
                    }
                    $tablerows[] = $tabledata;      //uses the roles to populate a multidimensional array
                    $row++;
                }
                fclose($input);
                if (isset($tablerows[$i])) {
                    return $tablerows[$i];              //uses argument to return the appropriate array
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here and how I might get all of the `<a>` elements without breaking the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out by myself. It turned out that because I didn't recognize some of the terminology on the MDN documentation, the documentation I was reading about the `indexOf()` method was for different types of arguments. So `a = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];` was returning just the first tag of the row of its current iteration, the tag was used by `txtValue` to return the string of `textContent` or `innerText` and `txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter)` compares the uppercase of those strings to the uppercase value of the input with the argument `filter`, toggling the if-else statement on the row of the current iteration to either hide or show the row.

I realized that `tr[i]`, which came from `table.getElementsByTagName("tr")` and would use the tag for the current iteration with `[i]` locating it on the array, was just supplying a tag for the node which was being used by `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` to get the row for the tag that was being returned there. So I realized if I just used `tr[i]` on its own, it would give me the whole row instead of the first `a` of the row. Worked like a charm.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); 
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        a = tr[i];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```